# How can I get the username of the loged in user on heroku console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, console

I am writing a tool that will info me who is logging in to the Heroku console.

I am already getting a message when the console is open, I just can't tell who opened it.

```
#config/initializers/console_spy.rb
ConsoleSpy.new.send_notification("DevName", "Console was opened")
```

so I get a notification when the console is open but I don't know who

*reference source https://getaround.tech/rails-console-spy/*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible yet via the heroku console.

You can however, track and monitor the heroku logs to find out who, when and at what time accessed the heroku console.

```
2019-04-12T15:48:05.727693+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by user me@mycompany.org
```

Comment: is there a way to get this info on the console, line not on the logs

Comment: Yes, simply issue the command `heroku logs` on the heroku console to get the most recent backup stash of logs :). If this is resolved, please mark as accepted answer.

Comment: Worth to note: users can start the rails console using the shorthand `rails c` command. So if you're using regex as part of your detection functions, you might want to look for this command also.